# Identifying line intersection in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, intersection

I have 1 shp line, I want to determine the intersection positions of the roads at 4 the intersection.

I used "intersection point at the road" but it gave an unexpected result (picture 1)

[image]

I want to results as picture 2

[image]

Is there any method to make it?

Comment: Why is that unexpected? The first image shows all the line intersections. The second image only shows two intersections. What makes those two intersections special?

Comment: Also, what is "intersection point at the road"? I don't see any tool, algorithm or plugin with that name.

Comment: Split your lines at the intersections and count intersecting features via SQL, e.g. `SELECT Count(*) FROM layerA WHERE ST_Intersects(layerA, layerB) = 1` and filter the points based on your desired no of intersections.